# gzip and webpack compression

Tags: webpack, compression, gzip

I can not make gzip work. I wanna make gzip files beforehand. I do that with compression-webpack-plugin. I use this files on server the usual way.

```
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))

app.get('*', (req: Object, res: Object) => {
  res.render('index')
})
```

And I refrence those files in my templaate.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Q</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="stylesLocal.29kf81a60pl57850llfi.js.gz">
</head>

  <body>
      <div id="app"><%- app %></div>
      <script src="bundle.2720b1a98103167676ac.js.gz"></script>
      <script src="vendor.57erz1a981hk5786756u.js.gz"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything works if I don't gzip the files but when i send .gz files it breaks. I am reading that I should set **Content-Encoding: gzip** and **Content-Type** and I tried that but whatever file content-type I put it complains since I am sending css, js and text file. Don't know how to make this work?

Comment: what do you mean by " but when i send .gz files it breaks. " ? how are you sending ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already have .gz files on the server. If you want Express to serve them, you need to us something like connect-gzip-static: https://github.com/pirxpilot/connect-gzip-static

## How it works

> We start by locating all compressed files (ie. files with
>   .gz and .br extensions) in root directory. All HTTP GET and HTTP HEAD
>   requests with Accept-Encoding header set to gzip are checked against
>   the list of compressed files and, if possible, fulfilled by returning
>   the compressed versions. If compressed version is not found or if the
>   request does not have an appropriate Accept- Encoding header, the
>   request is processed in the same way as standard static middleware would handle it.

Comment: Ok. I think I have something going. I used express-static-gzip but I am still not shure. The app works now. When I use **curl** i see **Content-Encoding: gzip** but when I inspect app wirh chrome dev tools under network, Response Headers there is no indication of gzip. Also I don't see any speed difference. It is the same. No I don't know if there is something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather,  You bundle the files, run the compression to get the .gz version available, and you HTML should call the NON-gzip version.

Does this show you what you want ?

https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4059/adding-gzip-to-webpack-using-compression-plugin

**EDIT**

remove the .gz

```
  <script src="bundle.2720b1a98103167676ac.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor.57erz1a981hk5786756u.js"></script>
```

Reason:  the browser tells the server if it supports GZip, if it does, it sends  the .gz version of the file, else it sends the text version.  The browser decodes the file, and loads it into the html.  All you see is the decoded version.

If the Server is sends the .gz version, but it is broken at the browser  then the .gz file is not correctly made.

Comment: Thanks Philip. That doesn't help me much. It basicly shows how to make .gz files with webpack. I do that to. I wanna know how to show them, render the content on the screen. I feel like something critical is missing. I keep seeing nginx but I am just developing locally now. I update my code to better represent what is going on. I have client and server bundle file. With client bundle I make .gz files. With server webpack I don't.  I am calling this files inside ejs/html. I am using extract-text-wenpack-plugin on client to extract css. In server bundle I use html-webpack-plugin for html.

Comment: What is the HTML example the browser sees ?  not the template on the server.

Comment: in the HTML remove the file extension  .gz IE:  bundle.2720b1a98103167676ac.js   The Server decides to use the .gz or not depending if the browser support GZIP

Comment: Under Recponse Header  I get:  Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8    Under netwprk I see all files and I see that they are gziped size but there is nowher eunder any of them Content-Encoding: gzip. Also It hangs at the first files saing Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream  and there is an error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for bundle and vendor file.

Comment: what is the full CURL header response ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147117/discussion-between-phillip-williams-and-igor-vuk).

Comment: Sorry Phillip, my internet connection broke. Thank you for your help again. I managed to run cURL. I get the same response header as in the browser. No indication og gzip. I will try again everything now when I removed .gz extension.

Comment: the one you said but after I have cd to the curl.exe

Comment: for bundle.js. I run this command curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" http://localhost:3001/bundle.2720b1a98103167676ac.js

Comment: for bundle.js. I run this command 
`curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" http://localhost:3001/bundle.2720b1a98103167676ac.js`